# Solr data-config: Fields Questions regarding TF-IDF

Tags: solr, indexing, tf-idf

We are using solr 1.4 (I know I know, pathetic :) )
in data-config

```
<!-- Snippet -->
<field column="description" stripHTML="true" stored="false" indexed="false"/>
```

Will the "description" data still be used to calculate the "score/tf-idf" value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The field should be marked as indexed true to be able to be used in the relevancy scoring.  i.e. `indexed=true`

> indexed=true|false
>   True - if this field should be "indexed". If (and
>   only if) a field is indexed, then it is **searchable**, sortable, and
>   facetable.

Comment: And the "stored=false" can I use it like that ?

Comment: stored does not affect searching. if the field is not marked stored you wont get back the field with Solr response.